# Does filter-method on QTable in Quasar work with typescript?

Tags: typescript, filtering, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using Vue3 with Vuex, Typescript and Quasar... I have a QTable that gets some data and I want to be able to filter them depending on the click of the buttons... I tried implementing filter-method but it seams like it doesn't get executed at any point in time... Does filter-method work with typescript? Does anyone have an example of it working?
I have table defined like this:

```
    <q-table
    :rows="rows"
    :columns="columns"
    row-key="rowId"
    selection="multiple"
    v-model:selected="selectObject"
    v-model:pagination="paginationObject"
    :filter="filterObject"
    :filter-method="customFilter">
```

and I have function defined in script as:

```
    const customFilter = (rows, terms, cols, cellValue) => {
      console.log(rows);
      console.log(terms);
      console.log(cols);
      console.log(cellValue);
      return [];
    };
    return{
      customFilter
    }
```

but that function is never getting executed no matter what I do... Can someone tell me what am I missing or doing wrong? Or how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?